# Control Life cycle of View Controllers when showing/hiding Container Views

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have created a `SegmentedControl`-based navigation in one of the views of my app. Each Segment corresponds to one `Container View` being shown (and the other(s) hidden).

I would ultimately want it so that View Controller being shown receives the `- (void) viewDidAppear` message and the View Controller being hidden receives the `- (void) viewWillDisappear` message.

Can this be achieved in a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

From what you say your implementation is not how a container view should be implemented. The idea with container views is to have a single container view in which you put the view controllers based on some events. So when the controllers are changed the lifecycle callbacks are called accordingly. There are plenty of tutorials on this, and you could also check out the [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) on this.
In your case when you press on a different segment the view controller should be changed in your container.

Comment: Are you saying that I should Instantiate and Embed another View Controller in a Single Container View when the user switches Segment? As far as I understood (though not from Apple Sources) it is pretty common to use put a few Container Views on top of each other and have only one of them not hidden (the "current" one) - But that might be wrong?

Comment: You should replace the view controller from the container with the new one when you tap the segmented control. I don't know where you read about hidden method but it is bad.

Comment: Noted. I will accept your answer when I have tried it.